# TYPO3 : StorageObject of related SubModels is empty in Extbase CommandController?

Tags: typo3, relationship, is-empty, domain-model, object-storage

I have a domain model, which has several 1:n relations to submodels.
Everything is fine when I open a related recordset in the TYPO3-BE, but if I get this object via repository => findByUid(), the ObjectStorages for those SubModels are empty. What may be the reason ? I checked all DocHeaders, and all ObjectStorage DocHints include the correct domain-model class.
I use TCA setup to set my own db-tablenames. Do I have to initialize those global settings in my controller before somehow maybe !?
Best regards and thanks in advance, Oliver

Comment: Can you please provide the PHPdoc comment section of the properties using `ObjectStorage` as type? It seems those are not completely correct...

Comment: It would be nice to get an answer from the questioner or a answer marked as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject needed repositories

```
/**
 * Your Repository
 *
 * @var \Vendor\Etension\Domain\Repository\NeededRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $neededRepository;
```

Comment: As stated in the question already, I already have the repository at hand. How shall I use ->findByUid method on a repository I dont yet have ?!  My Problem is, that objects returned by a specific repository do not contain data, they should be containing